# Using two lan cards, VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, internet

I am using a VPN software (Private Internet Access), which is installed in my PC and it works fine. But i need to use the converted internet connection on a device like xbox. it was configured a while ago but as soon as i switched to a different ISP it just stopped working. I have two lan cards installed in my pc. Lets say port "A" is that in which i plugged in the cable i got from my ISP and port "B" is that through which i am getting the converted internet and one end of this cable is in port "B" and other end is in my device.

Here's the problem. I am able to use internet on my computer very well but my device does not seems to be connected to internet. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows 7 on your PC, use following steps to share your VPN connection on LAN Port B:

1. Establish your VPN connection
2. Click on the network symbol in task bar, then choose "Open network and sharing center"
3. Select "Change Adapter Settings" on the left side. Now you will see all the physical and virtual network cards installed on your system.
4. There should be a virtual network card from your VPN software. Right click on it and select "Properties".
5. Switch to "Sharing" pane, and check "Allow other user to use this internet connection".

In this way the IP address on your network B will be changed to 192.168.137.1. There may be some warning messages about this, you may aknowlegde the warnings.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info, i never thought that i would be having a reply, but i am very much pleased.

Comment: However, i am still having issues. Its not connecting. Can anyone help? The port B is having the IP address 192.168.137.1 but i am not having internet access in Port B